# Rvm install ruby-2.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I had downloaded the rvm before with the ruby and the rails but it gave a problem that I could not solve, so I took the gems and imploded in the rvm, but now that I ask to install the ruby it does not, and when I give it A ruby -v appears that already is installed, the version 2.4.1, the same happens with the rails in version 4.2.6. what I do? What's happening?

```
rvm install ruby-2.4.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/16.04/x86_64/ruby-2.4.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system..
Installing required packages: gawk, libyaml-dev, autoconf, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, automake, bison, libffi-dev....
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install gawk libyaml-dev autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake bison libffi-dev',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1497634607_ruby-2.4.1/package_install_gawk_libyaml-dev_autoconf_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev_automake_bison_libffi-dev.log
  autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc bison-doc gawk-doc ncurses-doc
  libyaml-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake bison gawk libbison-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev
  libncurses5-dev libsigsegv2 libyaml-dev m4
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,462 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,047 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
++ return 100
++ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.

root@ubuntu:~# ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
root@ubuntu:~# rails -v
Rails 4.2.6
```

Comment: I solved this error I put in gemfile the `gem 'openssl', '2.0.4'` but now changed the error,

Comment: root@ubuntu:~/teste# rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run   `rails server -h`  for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting`

Comment: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'   ... 4462 levels...
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /root/teste/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I skirted the problem by changing the version of rails, like this:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: '4-2-stable'
```